# how to run node.js app from cmd with some predefined port in Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, cmd

Is it some command exist to run my node.js code with directly specified port?
something like `node server.js port=7777` ?

my server.js code looks like this

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (mount(req, res)) return;
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 80);
```

Comment: Just `set PORT=7777` from the command line then start node if you can't change the code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A simple adding to Alberto's answer. On Windows machine you haven't `export` command in `cmd`, use `set` instead.
Then the whole script will be looks like this:

```
set PORT=7777
node server.js
```

Note that the syntax in PowerShell is slightly different:

```
$env:PORT=7777
node server.js
```

Answer (score 12):

Depending on what `server.js` contains you should be able to do so.

At a minimum you should read `port` (you could use https://github.com/substack/node-optimist)

```
var argv = require('optimist').argv;
console.log(argv.port);

// use it like this
$ node server.js -port 7777
```

and then listen to it on your server (this depends on what lib you're using).

Run the server like this

```
export PORT=7777; node server.js
```

Comment: I update the question with server.js code. Is it possible to do that without modifying server.js content?

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni `node server.js -port 8000` this one saved my day. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I really love this approach. I did fiddle with the "optimistic" module at my end under Windows. There is an error in your example based on my setup. The command line should be `node server.js --port 7777` and you should install the module using `npm install optimistic`. Now I am able to pass the port in the command line of the node.exe program. But, I could not figure out how to debug this part. In VS Code I can only debug all other parts except the part which is listening to the server. Any feedback?

Comment: @tarekahf I suggest you to open a new question quoting this one as a reference

Answer (score 4):

On ubuntu I just do

```
PORT=7777 node .
```

in commandline, no set or export needed.

Comment: This works on Windows MINGW64 terminal that comes with Windows Git installation. Thanks! I used "PORT=7777 npm run dev" worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

for linux 
export PORT=5000;
node index.js

for windows
set PORT=5000;
node index.js

in case of powerShell

set $env:PORT=5000;
node index.js

const port  = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port,()=>{console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)})

Answer (score 0):

Use this on the command line:

```
http-server -p 7777
```